Receiving the following error in R Markdown: "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."
So, I am on a project, where the user can select an option and the output pdf should be generated accordingly as a pdf report. The Shiny app does work well and the pdf report too. I would like to just go one step further and customize the pdf report's styling to make it visually more attractive. To that end, I am pretty much using a similar customized pdf styling that I found online. However, I am having difficulty to apply the customized pdf style, written in .tex, to the dynamic pdf report made with RMarkdown. So, here is a sample code from the R Markdown document;
---
title: "`r unique(data_selected$aaa)` - AAA"
subtitle: BBB
geometry: margin=1in
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: true
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: pdf_report_styling.tex
---

# Header 1

some text here

`{r aaa}

data <- read_excel("data.xlsx")

data_selected <- data %>%
  filter(aaa == data$aaa)

table_gt <- data_selected %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(style = list(cell_fill(color = "lightgray")),
            locations = cells_body(columns = everything())
            )
table_gt

And the .tex  file I am using to customize my pdf report is this;
% load packages
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%% Set page size with a wider right margin
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, right=50mm}

%% Let's define some colours
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{D3D3D3}
\definecolor{highlight}{HTML}{800080}
\definecolor{dark}{HTML}{330033}

%% Let's add the border on the right hand side 
\AddToShipoutPicture{% 
    \AtPageLowerLeft{% 
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){% 
            \color{light}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
          }%
     }%
     % logo
          }

%% Style the page number
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyfootoffset{3.5cm}
}
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

%% style the chapter/section fonts
\chapterfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{20}{16.8}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{20}{16.8}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\color{dark}\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
  
% left align title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  {\sffamily\huge\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}} \vspace{0.3cm} \newline
  {\Large {\@subtitle}} \newline
  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

%% Use some custom fonts
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}[
    Path = fonts/Ubuntu/,
    Scale = 0.9,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    ]
    
\setmainfont{keplerstd}[
    Path = fonts/keplerstd/,
    Scale = 0.9,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = garr45w,
    BoldFont = bold,
    ItalicFont = italic
    ]

When the dynamic pdf report is tried to be generated the following error occurs;
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
I appreciate any comments and suggestions to fix the issue. Thank you for your kind attention beforehand.

There are a number of issues with your setup:

Inside your flushleft environment, you're issuing \newline, which is the cause of the issue ("There's no line here to end."). If you want a structured layout, it's best to set things inside a tabular. For example:
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
  \sffamily\huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@title}\strut \\
  \Large\strut\@subtitle \\
  \@author
\end{tabular}%

Note the use of \struts to use the current fontsize's "largest" element.
Alternatively, use \par at the end of a line before setting a new line of text.

The above, however, will still not work. Just because you're using title, subtitle (and author) in the YAML header doesn't necessarily mean that they will be available as \@title, \@subtitle (and \@author) in (La)TeX.  In fact, the only default title elements available are \@title, \@author (and \@date)... unless you use a document class that provides that (like KOMA-script).


